# Add X Days To Date, Excluding Weekends

Tags: php, date

I'm currently developing an online subscription application. I'm having some challenges on the part where the user will select the Number of Days to subscribe and then the Start Date. The PHP application should then be able to calculate the End Date excluding weekends.

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="startdate" type="text" />
    <input name="numberofdays" type="text" />
</form>
```

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came to this looking for the solution.
In the end I found a one line solution.

```
<?php 
    echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime("+10 weekdays"));
?>
```

Answer (score 23):

depends how the `startdate` is sent, but assuming you are using Y-m-d you can use [DateTime](http://uk.php.net/DateTime)

eg:

```
<?php 

    $_POST['startdate'] = '2012-08-14';
    $_POST['numberofdays'] = 10;

    $d = new DateTime( $_POST['startdate'] );
    $t = $d->getTimestamp();

    // loop for X days
    for($i=0; $i<$_POST['numberofdays']; $i++){

        // add 1 day to timestamp
        $addDay = 86400;

        // get what day it is next day
        $nextDay = date('w', ($t+$addDay));

        // if it's Saturday or Sunday get $i-1
        if($nextDay == 0 || $nextDay == 6) {
            $i--;
        }

        // modify timestamp, add 1 day
        $t = $t+$addDay;
    }

    $d->setTimestamp($t);

    echo $d->format( 'Y-m-d' ). "\n";

?>
```

Comment: You could use strtotime('+1day', $t) to get rid of magic numbers.

Comment: clever solution

Answer (score 4):

Same result, shorter version:

```
function addDays($days,$format="Y-m-d"){

    for($i=0;$i<$days;$i++){
        $day = date('N',strtotime("+".($i+1)."day"));
        if($day>5)
            $days++;
    }
    return date($format,strtotime("+$i day"));
}
```

Comment: Tranks! Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

My turn to propose a function that fix this problem :)

```
public static function addDaysToDate($startDate, $daysToAdd)
    {
        // loop for X days
        for ($i = 0; $i < $daysToAdd; $i++) {
            // get what day it is next day
            $nextDay = $startDate->modify('+1 day');
            
            // if it's Saturday or Sunday get $i-1
            if (in_array($nextDay->format('w'), [0, 6]) || self::isHoliday($nextDay->getTimestamp())) {
                $i--;
            }
        }
    return $nextDay;
}
```

isHoliday function is determining whether the day is a public holiday or not :

```
/**
 * Fonction permettant de retour la date de Pâques au format timestamp
 */
public static function easterDate($year)
{
    $a = $year % 4;
    $b = $year % 7;
    $c = $year % 19;
    $m = 24;
    $n = 5;
    $d = (19 * $c + $m ) % 30;
    $e = (2 * $a + 4 * $b + 6 * $d + $n) % 7;
    $easterdate = 22 + $d + $e;

    if ($easterdate > 31) {
        $day = $d + $e - 9;
        $month = 4;
    } else {
        $day = 22 + $d + $e;
        $month = 3;
    }

    if ($d == 29 && $e == 6) {
        $day = 10;
        $month = 04;
    } elseif ($d == 28 && $e == 6) {
        $day = 18;
        $month = 04;
    }
    return mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
}

/**
* Fonction permettant de retourner les jours fériés d'une année passée en paramètre
*/
public static function publicHolidays($year)
{
    if ($year === null) {
        $year = intval(strftime('%Y'));
    }

    $easterDate = self::easterDate($year);
    $easterDay = date('j', $easterDate);
    $easterMonth = date('n', $easterDate);
    $easterYear = date('Y', $easterDate);
    $holidays = array(
        // Jours fériés fixes
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year),// 1er janvier
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 1, $year),// Fête du travail
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 9, $year),// Fête de l'Europe
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 23, $year),// Fête nationale
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 8, 15, $year),// Assomption
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 1, $year),// Toussaint
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, $year),// Noël
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 26, $year),// Saint-Etienne

        // Jour fériés qui dépendent de Pâques
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $easterMonth, $easterDay + 1, $easterYear),// Lundi de Pâques
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $easterMonth, $easterDay + 39, $easterYear),// Ascension
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $easterMonth, $easterDay + 50, $easterYear), // Pentecôte
    );

    sort($holidays);

    return $holidays;
}

/**
 * Fonction permettant de savoir si un timestamp d'une date passée en paramètre est férié ou pas
 */
public static function isHoliday($timestamp)
{
    $iYear = strftime('%Y', $timestamp);
    $aHolidays = self::publicHolidays($iYear);
    /*
    * On est obligé de convertir les timestamps en string à cause des décalages horaires.
    */
    $aHolidaysString = array_map(function ($value) {
        return strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $value);
    }, $aHolidays);

    if (in_array(strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $timestamp), $aHolidaysString)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope that would help you !

Best regards,

Enes

Comment: Bravo, and thanks for the share. Sems perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a new function today that can help people who have this type of problem.

```
function sumDays($days = 0, $format = 'd/m/Y') {
    $incrementing = $days > 0;
    $days         = abs($days);
    $actualDate   = date('Y-m-d');

    while ($days > 0) {
        $tsDate    = strtotime($actualDate . ' ' . ($incrementing ? '+' : '-') . ' 1 days');
        $actualDate = date('Y-m-d', $tsDate);

        if (date('N', $tsDate) < 6) {
            $days--;
        }
    }

    return date($format, strtotime($actualDate));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **I have developed a new function today that can help people who have this type of problem. Depends how the startdate is sent, but assuming you are using Y-m-d you can use DateTime**

```
<?php  public static function getOrderEndDate( $start_date, $orderDaysCode ){

    $saturday_off = false;
    if( $orderDaysCode == 'meal_monthly_6' ) { $orderDays = 24; }
    elseif( $orderDaysCode == 'meal_monthly_5' ) {
        $orderDays = 20;
        $saturday_off = true;
    }elseif( $orderDaysCode == 'meal_weekly' ) {
        $orderDays = 5;
        $saturday_off = true;
    }
    else{ $orderDays = 1; }   // Daily Meal

    $formatted_date = new DateTime( $start_date );

    $date_timestamp = $formatted_date->getTimestamp();
    // loop for X days
    for( $i = 0; $i < ( $orderDays - 1 ); $i++ ) {
        // get what day it is next day
        $nextDay = date('w', strtotime('+1day', $date_timestamp) );
        // if it's Sunday or Saturday get $i-1
        if( $nextDay == 0 || ( $nextDay == 6 && $saturday_off ) ) { $i--; }
        // modify timestamp, add 1 day
        $date_timestamp = strtotime('+1day', $date_timestamp);
    }

    $formatted_date->setTimestamp($date_timestamp);

    return $formatted_date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
}

$orderEndDate = getOrderEndDate( '2020-06-17', 'meal_monthly_6' ); ?>
```