# Add 3 days to date fetched from DB expecting weekends

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with a status column and date column. I need to add 3 days to my date from the DB expecting weekends if status is 2 or 6. Here is my code:

```
$selectall = sqlsrv_query($conn, "select * from Table where and Status = 2 or status = 6", $params, $options);
    while($fetchall = sqlsrv_fetch_array($selectall))
    {
    $id = $fetchall['DATAID'];
        $dates = $fetchall['DATE'];
    if( 3 DAYS PAST )
    {
     sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS=5 WHERE DATAID=$ID")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this around my date variable

```
select
DATEADD(d,
    case when datepart(dw,'2017-05-17')=6 then 6 
         when datepart(dw,'2017-05-17')=7 then 5
         when datepart(dw,'2017-05-17')=1 then 4
         when datepart(dw,dateadd(d,3,'2017-05-17'))=7 then 5
         when datepart(dw,dateadd(d,3,'2017-05-17'))=1 then 4
         else 3 

    end
    ,'2017-05-17')
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I do not need to sum 3 days to today date. I have many dates there 2015-2017.

Comment: no problem, when I put 2017-05-17 that was just a date to test with.. youd put your column name in there

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how is this a JS question, but anyhow, you need to calculate date range in your php code and put that date range into your SQL query. AKA you take the start date, check which weekday it currently is and do respective mathematical calculations to add additional days.

Comment: I need code, not explanation. I know what i need to do, but do not know how to write code for this.

Comment: Then go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958712/add-x-days-to-date-excluding-weekends

Comment: That code is not working for me. It sum 3 days to date and do not expecting weekends

Answer (score 0):

```
 $selectall = sqlsrv_query($conn, "select * from Table where and Status = 2 or status = 6", $params, $options);
 while($fetchall = sqlsrv_fetch_array($selectall))
 {
 $DATAID= $fetchall['DATAID'];
 $dates = $fetchall['DATE'];
 $p = date("l");

 switch ($p) 
  {
   case "Wednesday" || "Thursday" || "Friday":
       $day = '-5 days';
       break;
   default:
       $day = '-3 days';
   }
 $s = date($dates);
 $today = date('Y-m-d');
 $totalday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day));
 if($totalday <= $s)
 {
   sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET STATUS = 5 WHERE DATAID=$dataid");
 }
}
```